# How do I label image segments generated from segmentation algriothm for a Convolutional Neural Network?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, neural-network, deep-learning, image-segmentation

I am using CNN(Convolutional Neural Network) to do remote sensing image classification. I first put the multi-band remote sensing image into image segmentation algorithm.

> *image segmentation is the process of partitioning a digital image into multiple segments (sets of pixels, also known as super-pixels).
>   The goal of segmentation is to simplify and/or change the
>   representation of an image into something that is more meaningful and
>   easier to analyze.[1][2] Image segmentation is typically used to
>   locate objects and boundaries (lines, curves, etc.) in images. More
>   precisely, image segmentation is the process of assigning a label to
>   every pixel in an image such that pixels with the same label share
>   certain characteristics.*(from wikipedia)

But my question is how to set  labels for these images segment in order to put the resized image segment to Convolutional Neural Network?

Answer (score 1):

If you already have labels for your multi-band images, just re-use the same label with the corresponding *"segments"*.

If you do not have labels, supervised learning might not be the best method unless you can generate them easily. But then, than depends on your problem. There are some tricks with image processing in order to extend your data base if you have only few labels (such as for instance, flipping images) but the question is too vague to answer more specifically about how exactly it should be applied to your multi-band segmented representation...